# Using File System object to make a log of files with a name that matches a string

Tags: vbscript, filesystemobject

I have a directory that contains many files with the same name nested in different folders and subfolders.  I'm trying to make a vbs script that will search through the directory and find any of files called "history" and write the name, path and date modified to a files.

I have successfully been able to make a script to return all the files in the folder, but haven't been able to make it so only the ones called "History" get written.  I was trying to add a If statement within the for so it would be like:

```
For Each ObjFolder In ObjSubFolders
    If ObjFolder.Name = "history*.*" Then
    ResultLogFile.WriteLine(ObjFolder.Name & vbab & ObjFolder.Path)
End If
```

But that was not working

This is what I have so far:

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Const TristateUseDefault = -2, TristateTrue = -1, TristateFalse = 0

Dim fso
Dim OutputFileName
Dim ResultLogFile


vCurrentDate = Now
'Year string
vCurrentYear = CStr(DatePart("yyyy",vCurrentDate))

'Month string
If DatePart("m",vCurrentDate) < 10 Then
    vCurrentMonth = "0" & CStr(DatePart("m",vCurrentDate))
Else
    vCurrentMonth = CStr(DatePart("m",vCurrentDate))
End If

'Day string
If DatePart("d",vCurrentDate) < 10 Then
    vCurrentDay = "0" & CStr(DatePart("d",vCurrentDate))
Else
    vCurrentDay = CStr(DatePart("d",vCurrentDate))
End If  

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

OutputFileName = "C:\historylogs\" & vCurrentYear & "-" & vCurrentMonth & "-" & vCurrentDay & ".tsv"

'MySourcePath = "C:\Test Folder\"
'Check if file already exists:

If fso.FileExists(OutputFileName) Then
    'File exists, so open it for appending and add no new header info:
    Set ResultLogFile = fso.OpenTextFile(OutputFileName, ForAppending, True, TristateTrue)
Else
    'File did not exist, so create it and add a header
    Set ResultLogFile = fso.OpenTextFile(OutputFileName, ForWriting, True, TristateTrue)
    'Create log headers
    ResultLogFile.WriteLine "FileName" & vbTab & "FilePath" & vbTab & "DateLastModified"
End If

GetFiles("C:\Test Folder")

Function GetFiles(FolderName)
    'On Error Resume Next

Dim ObjFolder
Dim ObjSubFolders
Dim ObjSubFolder
Dim ObjFiles
Dim ObjFile 

Set ObjFolder = fso.GetFolder(FolderName)
Set ObjFiles = ObjFolder.Files

'Write all files to output files
For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles
    ResultLogFile.WriteLine(ObjFile.Name & vbTab & ObjFile.Path & vbTab & ObjFile.DateLastModified)
Next
'Getting all subfolders
Set ObjSubFolders = ObjFolder.SubFolders

For Each ObjFolder In ObjSubFolders
    'Writing SubFolder Name and Path
    ResultLogFile.WriteLine(ObjFolder.Name & vbab & ObjFolder.Path)

    'Getting all Files from subfolder
    GetFiles(ObjFolder.Path)
Next

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it a few ways.. change this if..

```
For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles
  ResultLogFile.WriteLine(ObjFile.Name & vbTab & ObjFile.Path & vbTab & ObjFile.DateLastModified)
Next
```

..you want to find any file with history in the name, regardless where:

```
For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles
  If InStr(1, ObjFile.Name, "history") Then
    ResultLogFile.WriteLine(ObjFile.Name & vbTab & ObjFile.Path & vbTab & ObjFile.DateLastModified)
  End If
Next
```

..you want to find all files that start with history:

```
For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles
  If LCase(Mid(ObjFile.Name, 1, 7)) = "history" Then
    ResultLogFile.WriteLine(ObjFile.Name & vbTab & ObjFile.Path & vbTab & ObjFile.DateLastModified)
  End If
Next
```

EDIT: Responding to your comment, you could have a recursive sub like this. It will search all folders and subfolders, for any file that starts with whatever you pass.. so if you pass "history" and file history* will be found.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Call findFiles(objFSO.GetFolder("C:\temp"), "history")

Sub findFiles(objFolder, strMatchString)

  For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
    Call findFiles (objSubFolder, strMatchString)
  Next

  Set objFiles = objFolder.Files

  For Each objFile In objFiles
    If LCase(Mid(objFile.Name, 1, Len(strMatchString))) = LCase(strMatchString) Then
      MsgBox objFile.Name & vbTab & objFile.Path & vbTab & objFile.DateLastModified
    End If
  Next 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! that works for getting the history files out of the main folder, but there are also some in the subfolders
I'm tried this but itThanks! that works for getting the history files out of the main folder, but there are also some in the subfolders

Comment: Edited my post responding to your comment. You would need to change MsgBox to ResultLogFile.WriteLine object and remove some unneeded code but that should do what you're asking for.